# Android Application gets crashed

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview, main-activity

The app crash because of the following code lines.

I have **two string-array** in a `XML` file named as `Telephones` in a folder named **values** and two `TextView` in **text.xml**.

I can not figure out what's going wrong here.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] name= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
    String[] number= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text, name);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text, number);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
}
 }
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your xml files and the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: Post your logcat... and btw, why you set two adapters in the same list??? it's really strange!

Comment: I don't  know actually but I need to a sub item under item in the listview, so I need 2 textview I think,but how can create it?

Comment: **No**, ListView not work like that. [Here](http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/) is an example of ListView with two TextViews. And post your logcat if you want some help in this OP.

Comment: If I can't how can I add sub items with ArrayAdapter<String> ? because I have a long list

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add TextView id in MainActivity java but after adding the names_txt won't show up the only one show up is numbers_txt, how fix it please?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] name= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
    String[] number= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text, R.id.names_txt, name);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text, R.id.numbers_txt, number);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
}



    }
```